# Does a character need knowledge of a creature to Polymorph or Wild Shape into it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters, class-feature, polymorph

Can a character with Wild Shape or casting Form of the Dragon/Monstrous Physique/Elemental Shape/etc. shift into any form (meeting the size requisites) that the player knows of, or do they need knowledge of the for form to be taken?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112149/does-a-character-need-knowledge-of-a-creature-to-summon-into-it) but distinct.

Comment: Why don't you separate question about wildshape and about spells? Rules are totally independent from each other. This looks like two questions squeezed into one.

Comment: Wild Shape uses the same polymorph rules. If there's a difference it should be nuanced enough to fit into an answer imo. If the Stack disagrees I can change it later.

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62504/23058) but different from the other related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the spells you've listed mention a familiarity requirement, so by default there is none.

[Wild Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-):

> At 4th level, a druid gains the ability to turn herself into any small
>   or Medium animal and back again once per day. Her options for new
>   forms include all creatures with the animal type. This ability
>   functions like the beast shape I spell, except as noted here. The
>   effect lasts for 1 hour per druid level, or until she changes back.
>   Changing form (to animal or back) is a standard action and doesn’t
>   provoke an attack of opportunity. **The form chosen must be that of an
>   animal the druid is familiar with.** ...  As a druid gains levels, this ability allows the druid to take on the form of larger and smaller animals, elementals, and plants.

So for *animals*, Wild Shape requires familiarity. The wording is not entirely clear on whether this requirement extends to plant and elemental forms.

For elemental forms the ambiguity doesn't matter much, because a druid can easily use Summon Nature's Ally to acquire familiarity before they get the appropriate Elemental Wild Shape ability. So plants are the major area of uncertainty.